# The contactor doesn't switch ON during the Off-peak hours (French installation)

Tags: water-heater

My water heater works well in when I set the contactor to "forced mode".  But it doesn't work in "auto mode" (it should switched ON during off-peak period, but it doesn't). (It's in an french house)

- In forced mode, there are 230V between terminals 1 and 3 which are connected to the hot water tank
- In auto mode and during off-peak hours, there is no tension between terminals 1 and 3, nor between terminals A1 and A2  which should switch one the contactor during the off-peak period.

[image: Compteur linky: les heures creuses ne déclenchent pas le contacteur]

The contactor connections of my electrical circuit are different from all those I found online :
● The A2 terminal has two red wires:

- "A2 left" which is connected to terminal 1 of a "Consumption Indicator" marked "OP" (at the top left)
- "A2 right" which is connected to C1 of the main electricity meter counter (and the two terminal C1 and C2 of this electricity meter are in continuity : in the photo the red line indicates this continuity)
- The A1 terminal has a blue wire: it goes directly behind the link counter without being connected to C1 or C2

On the divisional counter ( [Tywatt30](http://www.deltadore.com/mediastore/23/5684_3_EN_original.pdf)) I have this (it doesn't change during off-peak hours):

[image: Tywatt30]

Any advice is warmly welcome!

Comment: What is providing the time of day? Since the force works it would be related to a programming of what is peak hours or when it is supposed to turn on.  My mom has off peak metering and she had me install timers on several things that really did not to run during the day. The battery in that unit died but it was still displaying time, could this be the issue?

Comment: The main electricity "smart" meter counter is programmed to send the signal at the right time. (It's on the right part of the pictures. The signal comes from the 2 screws/contactors which are, I dont know why, connected with each other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.

The important information is that C2 should beconnected to a live (red) wire (always: during off-peak "HC" and "HP"). So you should aways find 230V between C2 and the blue wire ("phase"). It wasn't the case so I just followed the (black) wire.

The circuit was divided into 2 power switchboard, one a circuit breaker without label was turned OFF. It disconnected the black wire from the live wire.